# Prove equivalence of $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Prove equivalent of $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_\infty$ on the vector space of polynomial functions with degree $\leq 1$.

My idea was to upper bound $||\cdot||_1$ with $||\cdot||_\infty$ and vice-versa:

$$||\cdot||_1 \leq m_1 ||\cdot||_\infty$$

$$||\cdot||_\infty \leq m_2 ||\cdot||_1$$

Polynomials of degree 1 have the form

$$f(x) = mx + n$$ so that

$$||f||_1 = \int_0^1 |mx + n|dx = |\frac{m}{2} + n|$$

$$||f||_\infty = sup \{ |mx + n|, x \in [0,1] \} = |m + n|$$

$$|\frac{m}{2} + n| \leq m_1 |m + n|$$

$$(\frac{m}{2} + n)^2 \leq m_1^2 (m + n)^2$$

$$m_1^2 = \left( \frac{0.5m + n}{m + n} \right)^2$$

$$lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{0.5m + n}{m + n} = 1$$

Such that $m_1 = 1$.

Is this correct? And how can I solve for $m_2$?

Comment: $ \int_0^1 |mx + n|dx = |\frac{m}{2} + n|$ is wrong. $\sup \{ |mx + n|, x \in [0,1] \} = |m + n|$ is also wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: An hint for the $\|\cdot\|_1$. We need to consider cases for the integral of the absolute value function, $\int_a^b|f(x)|dx$. Such functions are defined as $|f(x)| = \begin{cases}f(x), \text{ if } f(x) \geq 0\\ -f(x), \text{ if } f(x) < 0\end{cases}$. This is telling us that we need to consider cases for the integral of $f(x) = mx+n$.

Comment: The case $m=0$ is obvious. For $m\neq 0$ by homogeneity you can reduce to the case $f(x)=x+n.$